# Google Maps API V3 - Move "From" and "To" markers and repopulate search field

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know how to create a custom marker, but what I want to do is make a function that will set the "From" and "To" markers (or A and B as they're shown on the map) to wherever I click and then update the search box with the new locations.

For example let's say I have a route from 123 Fake Street to 123 Madeup Lane, the From and To search boxes will say 123 Fake Street and 123 Madeup Lane, respectively. When I run this particular function, I want the marker to move and replace the "From" and "To" search boxes with the new marker locations.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this working example [HERE](http://www.geocodezip.com/inventoresdegaragem_com_dbteste_indexA.html). Click on the map, the first click will be your starting point, while the second click on map will be the destination point.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event){

                var fromLat = event.latLng.lat();
                var fromLong = event.latLng.lng();
                var markLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(fromLat, fromLong);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: markLatLng,
                    map: map
                });

                document.getElementById('field_from').value = markLatLng;
                var start = document.getElementById('field_from').value
                var end = document.getElementById('field_to').value;

                var request = {
                    origin:start,
                    destination:end,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
                });

                markersArray.push(marker);

                });
```

Solved it, if anyone is interested.